# Buzzing Noise on Dell inspiron 5559 with Kubuntu 16.04!

Tags: 16.04

I installed kubuntu 16.04 on my dell inspiron 5559, unfortunately notebook makes a buzzing noise. How to resolve this problem?

Comment: Please add more info.

Comment: Can you identify from where the sound is coming from. For example Processor fan or CD drive etc.

Comment: OS: Kubuntu 16.04
Kernel: LInux 4.8.0-040800-generic
Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
Model Notebook: Dell Inspiron 5559

The buzzing noise come out from the speaker.

Comment: Buzzing noise from a speaker is usually caused by a hardware problem. Boot a live USB flash drive that has a different OS installed on it. Does the buzzing noise persist? If so, then it is probably caused by a hardware issue.